# Conditional matching with multiple fields comparison in different files using AWK

Tags: awk, aix

I need your assistance again on how to match 2 fields/columns in 2 separate files including conditional matching of record (status <> 'X' in Employee.txt & availability = 'Y' in Car.txt). Employee.txt ($1 - employee #, $2 - sport). Car.txt ($4 - employee #, $2 - sport). Below is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Employee1.txt (last column is the **status**)
1|canoeing|Sam|Smith|Seatle|X
2|jogging|Barry|Jones|Seatle|
3|football|Garry|Brown|Houston|
4|jogging|George|Bla|LA|X
5|basketball|Celine|Wood|Atlanta|
6|tennis|Jody|Ford|Chicago|

Car1.txt (last column is **availability**)
100|football|blue|5|Y
110|tennis|green|9|N
120|hockey|yellow|8|N
130|football|yellow|6|N
140|jogging|red|2|Y
150|canoeing|white|0|
    
awk -F"|" '
NR==FNR {
  if ($NF == "Y")
     car[$4,$2]
     next
}
{
    print > ($NF != "X" && ($1,$2) in car ? "match.txt" : "no_match.txt")
}' Car.txt Employee.txt

no_match.txt is the same as Employee.txt. Zero records in match.txt.

Desire output:
match.txt
2|jogging|Barry|Jones|Seatle|
5|basketball|Celine|Wood|Atlanta|

no_match.txt
3|football|Garry|Brown|Houston|
6|tennis|Jody|Ford|Chicago|
```

Thanks so much,
George

Comment: Please separate that monolithic grey block of text into individual blocks for input, output, and code files with your explanatory text in between.

Comment: You should install some relational database for such tasks. (E.g. Access, Sqlite, MySql).

Comment: I already have but just want to gather the data before doing a massive record update. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: according to your requirement,

```
5|basketball|Celine|Wood|Atlanta|
```

**shouldn't** be in match.txt, because the sports are different in the two files (**football vs basketball**)

If you want `status "X"` entries in the "no_match.txt":

```
$  awk -F"|" '                
NR==FNR { if ($NF == "Y") car[$4 FS $2]=1; next }
{ print > ( ($NF!="X" && ($1 FS $2) in car) ? "match.txt" : "no_match.txt") }' c.txt e.txt
```

result:

```
kent$  head match.txt no_match.txt
==> match.txt <==
2|jogging|Barry|Jones|Seatle|

==> no_match.txt <==
1|canoeing|Sam|Smith|Seatle|X
2|jogging|Barry|Jones|Seatle|
3|football|Garry|Brown|Houston|
4|jogging|George|Bla|LA|X
5|basketball|Celine|Wood|Atlanta|
6|tennis|Jody|Ford|Chicago|
```

If you want to exclude the "X" entries:

```
kent$  awk -F"|" '                
NR==FNR { if ($NF == "Y") car[$4 FS $2]=1; next }
$NF!="X"{ print > (($1 FS $2) in car? "match.txt" : "no_match.txt") }' c.txt e.txt
```

Result:

```
kent$  head match.txt no_match.txt
==> match.txt <==
2|jogging|Barry|Jones|Seatle|

==> no_match.txt <==
3|football|Garry|Brown|Houston|
5|basketball|Celine|Wood|Atlanta|
6|tennis|Jody|Ford|Chicago|
```

Comment: awk -F"|" '
NR==FNR {
        if ($NF == "Y")
                car[$4 FS $2]=1; next
}
{
        print > ( ( ($NF != "X") && ($1 FS $2) in car) ? "match.txt" : "no_match.txt")
}
Got the same output. Your last print statement did not work with a syntax error. Thanks for helping out Kent!